# Ruby on Rails Problems with Views (rhml / html.erb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with regards to views in ruby on rails.

Basically I have a regular project which lists the details just fine on

`http://localhost:3000/stores/` which loads the code found within `index.html.erb`

Now, i have scaffolding etc all in place, however when i try to load

`http://localhost:3000/stores/search` which SHOULD load code from `search.rhtml` (should this be changed to .html.erb or it doesnt make a difference?), its simply going to the file `show.html.erb` and displaying that code instead (which results in an error due to properties not being passed etc).

I was wondering what i'm doing wrong, am i supposed to set something up in the routes.rb file?? (if this has anything to do with the issue?)

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :stores
  map.resources :stores

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Thanks a lot in advanced for any assistance as this is my first Ruby on Rails project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to add a search action you'd want to set your routes file like this:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :stores, :collection => { :search => :get }

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

I would stick with naming the file `search.html.erb` although `search.rhtml` will work too. This is a [good guide for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in rails and [here's the section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) that specifically applies to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer each question:

1. You have a duplicate `map.resources :stores`, one is enough.
2. Yes you are correct `http://localhost:3000/stores/search` will load search.html.erb (better to name it that way to follow coventions) (I don't see the code from your controller but as you seems in the process of learning rails I assume you did not tweak the controller action with respond_to)
3. It should not go to the show.html.erb view. Can you show us your StoresController?